# React what does merge() do?

Tags: reactjs

So Im reading someone else's code and I saw a function is using a `merge()` inside `setState()`
The function is taking in a list as below

```
handleFilterChange = (filters: List<Map<string, any>>) => {
  if (filters) {
    this.setState({ form: this.state.form.merge({ filters }) }, () => {
      this.loadItemMetaList()
    });
  }
};
```

The `this.loadItemMetaList()` is just a function loads the metadata for the item. It calls a redux action creator `loadAssetMetaList()`.

Does anyone know what the `merge()` method do? I tried to right click and look into the definitions but it says no definition found for 'merge'. And there is no import statement about this `merge()` above this js file.

Comment: It's not related to react, but with this form state implementation instead.

Comment: It is from this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-form-state